# Оптимизировать код си шарп (Поисковая строка)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Делаю на WPF.

Есть TextBox, в который вписывается название страны, я это название сравниваю с radiobutton'ами, которые находятся в listBox'e. Да вот только сравниваю все через if\else, и выглядит это все некрасиво, может, можно как то записать через цикл или еще как то?

```
            if(tbSearch.Text == europe.England.Content.ToString())
            {
                europe.Show();
                europe.England.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else if(tbSearch.Text == europe.Island.Content.ToString())
            {
                europe.Show();
                europe.Island.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else if(tbSearch.Text == europe.Nederland.Content.ToString())
            {
                europe.Show();
                europe.Nederland.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else if(tbSearch.Text == europe.Germany.Content.ToString())
            {
                europe.Show();
                europe.Germany.IsChecked = true;
            }
```

tb - TextBox

Europe - Window

Germany... - Radiobutton

Мне советовали воспользоваться Dictionary или Tag, вот только я не смог в них разобраться из найденной информации.

Спасибо.

Comment: можете через switch оформить, но тоже вариант так себе:)

Comment: воспользуйтесь методом europe.Items - эта коллекция, а через него можете попробовать запустить операцию foreach. к каждому элементу можно обратиться europe.Items[0].

Comment: А можно скриншот того, что вы делаете, ну чтоб представить с чем имеем дело... А так, ответ вам прост - уберите из xaml все `name` теги и забудьте про обращение к контролам из кода, это сподвигнет вас к реализации binding, а с ним и MVVM....

Comment: Пробовал сделать проверку:  if(tbSearch.Text == europe.listBoxEurope.Items[i].ToString()).
Вот только справа не текст... 
А скриншот чего нужно, Си#, XAML, или формы?)
Мб прикрепить(если можно) само приложение?

Comment: @byNeznayka Мне нужно видеть как выглядит само приложение, как Radiobutton находятся в listbox, для чего они там итд. Пока я вообще не представляю на кой вам в листбоксы засовывать Radiobutton, для чего выделение делать и как должно себя вести уже выделенное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Добавил скрины, если что пояснить по ним, сразу пишите)

Comment: @byNeznayka Хорошо... кидайте лучше проект архивом xD

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прикрепил ссылку на диск. Так нужно было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот открыл я ваш проект и... Эх, а я вам хотел все по канонам, на MVVM написать, ну да ладно. Весь ваш код можно переписать примерно следующим образом:

```
var control = europe.listBoxEurope.Items.OfType<RadioButton>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content.ToString() == tbSearch.Text);

if (control != null)
{
    europe.Show();
    control.IsChecked = true;
}
```

А что касается самого кода, вот вам пару наставлений:

1. Ваш проект не запустится у кого либо еще, ибо вы используете абсолютные пути к файлам ("C:/MyProject/file.txt"), на другом компьютере данных папок попросту не может быть! Используйте относительные пути ("/file.txt"), а лучше и вовсе используйте методы определения текущей директории проекта!
2. Зачем вы на каждый континент создаете свое окно, которое отличается только задним цветом? Создайте одно окно и передавайте в него необходимые данные!
3. Мой вам совет, перепишите все на MVVM, разделите логику на слои, будет в сто раз удобней чем сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает отлично, только вот я, честно говоря, не понимаю кое каких символов. Сможете объяснить, если не сложно, что значит: "=>", <RadioButton>()".
К наставлениям постараюсь прислушаться, только вот скажите, wpf стоит того, что бы его сейчас учить или, может быть, уже устарел\стал не нужен?

Comment: @byNeznayka Все это LINQ `=>` - это [Лямбда](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.16.php), с помощью которой мы задаем определенное условие (в нашем случае мы говорим, что хотим проверить каждый объект (x) в Items на соответствие тексту. `<RadioButton>()` - это присвоение к типу, то есть мы вызываем опять же LINQ метод `OfType<T>`, где T - это [обобщение](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php) с помощью которого создается один метод для множества типов. По поводу языка, а вы знаете что то лучше? На Desktop в c# приложения пишутся либо на WinForms, WPF или UWP, последний - это win 10.